# What's the difference between Interior and Exterior scaffolding?

Tags: ladder

I've been looking into getting some scaffolding for some jobs around the house. Honestly, I may need it for both inside and outside.

I see various products where they specifically list scaffolding as being "interior" or "exterior". I cannot find an explanation anywhere.

Can I use exterior scaffolding indoors? Can I use interior scaffolding outside? Is there a difference? Do I need to get both?

FYI: Since I have no idea how to tag this (I used ladder because places like to group scaffolding and ladders), I fear it may be off topic. If so, please advise where I can ask this question.

Comment: Guessing, but I would expect that exterior is stronger, has better feet, is better cross-braced, etc. since it may go up a much greater distance. Possibly better protection against rust.

Comment: Also guessing, but I'd think interior has softer feet (/wheels?) and possibly limited height, where outdoor would be seemingly infinitely stackable. Out of curiosity, what kind of interior heights are you facing?

Comment: You can never go wrong with exterior and put extra floor protection down when using it inside.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I've got a vaulted ceiling < 12 feet. Most of the need would be for working on the 2nd story outside.

Comment: It could also do with anchoring methods.  The scaffolding my dad used when we resided our 2 story home when I was a kid was partially stabilized by brackets nailed to studs in the wall.  Not something you'd want to use inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really going to have to look at them up close & personal if a simple 2x12 across 2 or more supports isn't to your liking. Interiors are either a fancy version of the 2x12 on empty 5-gallon buckets or self-standing & rolling cages of quite short lengths.

Exterior usually is not self-standing & must be anchored to the building, negating its use inside altogether, but they are made to receive additional sections & levels.

If you haven't used ladders & ladder jacks for exterior scaffolding you may want to try that out first & they can be used indoors with the Werner type of adjustable ladders that can be used as step or straight ladders.